Keyboard sending wrong codes for certain key combinations only to linux terminals, tried everything. So confused
I had been trying out a few different linux distros over the past few days and ended up back in Windows. I noticed that in WSL ubuntu shift-home wasn’t working properly—it would print out the letter H. Same with most every key non-character or numpad key on the right side of the keyboard as well as function keys. They all worked as expected except when shift was held down. Then they’d print out something out of left field (shift-arrow keys, for example, prints out A, B, C, and D). After many hours of trouble shooting, literally all day, I’ve arrived at the conclusion that it must be some sort of motherboard issue. It persists on Windows and Linux installs and even in web terminals to random “sandbox” installs. Even in a leftover grub loader from a distro I had uninstalled. It persists with any attached hardware, even with everything else unplugged but a $10 wired keyboard. Even using the on-screen keyboard in Windows 11.
I recently updated the bios a few days ago, I’m not sure if that’s what triggered it as in Linux I had been using Warp terminal which just used a standard text box for input. Anyway I tried reflashing the bios, turning on or off every relevant setting I could find, all with no luck. Completely out of ideas, I eventually formatted all of my drives and reinstalled Windows from fresh media and still the problem persists. I’m baffled on this one. I started out this thinking it’d be an easy fix for some WSL bug now I’m questioning existence. WHY ONLY LINUX TERMINALS???
So, yeah, anyone have any ideas? Z690 GAMING X (rev. 1.0/1.1) is the motherboard, let me know if there’s any more info I can provide that would be helpful.

The keyboard doesn't know what apps it's talking to (and apps don't know what keyboard they're talking to). The only place actual keyboard inputs go is your OS, where they're converted to Windows-specific or Linux-specific events, then sent to the apps.
(Neither does the BIOS, and for that matter, the only time keyboard is handled by the BIOS at all is when you're running MS-DOS or staring at the BIOS setup screen. At all other times, when a real OS is running, it doesn't use the BIOS keyboard services anymore.)
So if it only happens in specific apps, then it means your operating system has already received the keys correctly, and it's most likely the apps that are handling them differently.

WHY ONLY LINUX TERMINALS???

Because terminal-based programs handle special keys completely differently from "normal" apps. And because due to their varied history (as they still kinda emulate physical terminals that didn't even have half the capabilities that the app now does), they often disagree as to how to handle some things.
The terminal emulator app itself receives the Shift-arrows perfectly fine, since it is a standard Windows or Linux desktop app. Programs running inside the terminal, however, cannot use Windows-like key events – they use VT220/ANSI/ECMA/xterm keycodes, where all special keys are encoded as text starting with the ESC byte.

The "Arrow up" key, for example (without Shift or other modifiers), is sent as the characters Esc [ A, like the original physical terminals did.

"Home" is usually sent as Esc [ 4 ~ per DEC style, but not always; I think Esc [ H is another valid option that comes from a different physical system originally.
(Now the issues start. Many terminal-based apps (i.e. those running inside the terminal app) accept both sequences, but some only accept what terminfo says is correct, and terminfo can only list one key per terminal type...which doesn't work when different terminals send different keys but still indicate they're emulating the same type.)

Shift-arrows and Ctrl-arrows have probably three or four different ways to handle them. It's still a headache to this day. For example, the commonly used Xterm style is to encode Shift+Up as Esc [ 1 ; 2 A.



It's that the issue persists despite changing every possible thing I can think to change. Different keyboards (even windows on screen keyboard), different OSs (windows, mint, opensuse, random ones I found for "playground" use on the web) and even persists after flashing the BIOS and formatting all hard drives

It seems that you haven't changed the program that runs inside the terminal, and you were trying this against the same Bash every single time.
Bash just works that way; it does not have generic understanding of Xterm-style key sequences – e.g. it'll handle Ctrl-arrows if those are explicitly programmed in, but Shift-arrows (and things like Ctrl-Home, etc) will not be consumed correctly. It will read part of the sequence, stop halfway at "that's none of the keys I know", and the rest (e.g. the last A of ESC[1;2A) will just be read as regular input.
Some distributions customize it through their provided /etc/inputrc, and some users customize it through their own ~/.inputrc (maybe even as part of a bundled "shell theme"), so it's possible that at one time you were using a distribution that had this covered, whereas by default it's broken.
(In fact, even my own ~/.inputrc has both Xterm-style "\e[1;5C" and older-style "\e[OC" to make Bash correctly handle Ctrl-left.)
And generally this is going to be different in every program that runs inside the terminal; Bash works differently from Vim, Vim works differently from Nano, Nano works differently from Irssi, and so on.

Thanks for the response. Yeah, I get that terminals are different in that way, which is why I went through hours and hours of troubleshooting just assuming there was something weird with my terminal emulator, or xterm setup, or whatever. That's not what has me confused though. It's that the issue persists despite changing every possible thing I can think to change. Different keyboards (even windows on screen keyboard), different OSs (windows, mint, opensuse, random ones I found for "playground" use on the web) and even persists after flashing the BIOS and formatting all hard drives.

Yes, but you're still running the exact same app (Bash) within all those terminals, aren't you? Have you considered that it just works like that by default?

Well I did consider that initially, I just asked gpt or whatever "hey how do I get shift-home to select a line instead of printing H in WSL" and it was like "yeah, something must be wrong with your terminal" and sent me off on wild goose chase of troubleshooting. And then I went googling and couldn't find the answer (maybe I was just searching for the wrong thing), then more chatbots. Claude, Microsoft Copilot, Ollama, GPT 4--none of them told me "hey, that's just how it works." I feel pretty stupid.
